# UI still locked up even with multi threading

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I'm working on a project and I've hit a lot of road blocks with the UI.
In this case  create a new thread to update the UI so that the UI main thread is left open allowing you to still use the UI.

I'm not sure what the problem with this is. I think that maybe I'm using dispatcher to create thread that instead of creating a thread uses the main thread?? Its also worth noting that my `MainWindow` is singleton instance.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    if (go)
    {
        city = textBox.GetLineText(0);
        if (city == "exit")
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
                    delegate
                    {
                       this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(start));
                    }));
         t1.Start();
         //await Task.Run(() => start());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you starting a new thread only to immediately invoke back on the dispatcher?

Comment: Dispatcher.Invoke() executes the action *in* the thread you're invoking into, thus blocking both that and the one you're calling from, together. Use sparingly! You need it only if you touch UI, and it's not needed to set properties that raise PropertyChanged, even if UI responds to them. Your `start()` method would usually, at most, use it to update ObservableCollections. Depending on what's in it, you might even be fine just passing `start` as the thread proc. But see IDisposable's fine answer below -- that's the best idiom to use.

Comment: if i call dispatcher later in the start method can i join the ui process to the ui thread with dispatcher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create a new thread. When you're using async and await, a new thread will be automatically assigned from the thread pool. Just make your **button_Click** event handler async as mentioned in code below and call the long running task using `await` keyword.

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (go)
    {
        city = textBox.GetLineText(0);
        if (city == "exit")
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        await Task.Run(() => start());
    }
}
```

What will happen here is when you click on the button the event will be handled. If the condition is satisfied, the long running task is initiated in this line `await Task.Run(() => start());`. Then it will return to the UI thread without blocking it ie the UI will still be responsive while another thread is executing the long running process in background.

Please read [Asynchronous Programming with async and await (C#) on MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx)

**EDIT :** 
Since you want to control UI elements in your `start()` method, use the below approach :

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (go)
    {
        city = textBox.GetLineText(0);
        if (city == "exit")
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        await start();
    }
}

private async Task start()
{
    await Task.Run(async () => 
    {
       // long running task here
    });   

    // UI Control code here.
}
```

Comment: yeah i was trying you use async/await earlier but the problem is the that start has ui elements so it needs to be sta  so that diddnt work

Comment: that worked great for the ui thanks. its not doing the long running task yet but im going to play with it see if i can figure something out because its not throwing an error either

Comment: Is there any other blockage for running that task? Please put breakpoint and check.

Comment: thats what i did an your code looks good im going to have to rework mine to make it work for it but it is calling the method. Thanks again. Oh and im pretty new is there anything i need to do when the problem has been solved

Comment: If you got the point, you can mark the answer as correct answer by clicking on the green tick.

Comment: Update: Thanks again. I did rewrite my code and it works without issue. it maybe helpful to someone in the future that i did later have to use dispatcher because i have to call the start method multiple times